# When a JdbcTemplate object is instantiated using a DataSource object, does it open a connection?

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a piece of code inside my constructor that looks like this:

```
public class Foo {
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public Foo(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate( dataSource );
    }
}
```

My question is: When the JdbcTemplate object is created, does it obtain a connection from the connection pool and hold it in use?

I'm asking this question because I want to avoid the situation where instantiating a Foo object takes up a connection from the pool and holds it. Such an arrangement will mean rapid exhaustion of my connection pool just from bean instantiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have two distinct questions in this post.

Let's take one at a time.

### When a JdbcTemplate object is instantiated using a DataSource object, does it open a connection?

No, creating JdbcTemplate object does not open the connection to the Database. It does not even create it.

We can see the source code of `afterPropertiesSet()` method, which is invoked in the `JdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource)` constructor:

```
@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() {
    if (getDataSource() == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Property 'dataSource' is required");
    }
    if (!isLazyInit()) {
        getExceptionTranslator();
    }
}
```

The moment, when the connection is *actually* opened is when you invoke one of the query methods of JdbcTemplate API.

For instance, the `execute(ConnectionCallback<T> action)` method, looks like this:

```
@Override
@Nullable
public <T> T execute(ConnectionCallback<T> action) throws DataAccessException {
    Assert.notNull(action, "Callback object must not be null");

    Connection con = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(obtainDataSource());
    try {
        // Create close-suppressing Connection proxy, also preparing returned Statements.
        Connection conToUse = createConnectionProxy(con);
        return action.doInConnection(conToUse);
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        // Release Connection early, to avoid potential connection pool deadlock
        // in the case when the exception translator hasn't been initialized yet.
        String sql = getSql(action);
        DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, getDataSource());
        con = null;
        throw translateException("ConnectionCallback", sql, ex);
    }
    finally {
        DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, getDataSource());
    }
}
```

---

Second question which you are asking in the actual body of your question is:

### Do the JdbcTemplate query methods API reuse the JDBC connection or they create new one each time?

Let's have a look at `DataSourceUtils.getConnection(obtainDataSource());` method, which, in turn, *tries* `doGetConnection(dataSource)`. The source code of latter looks as follows:

```
public static Connection doGetConnection(DataSource dataSource) throws SQLException {
    Assert.notNull(dataSource, "No DataSource specified");

    ConnectionHolder conHolder = (ConnectionHolder) TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(dataSource);
    if (conHolder != null && (conHolder.hasConnection() || conHolder.isSynchronizedWithTransaction())) {
        conHolder.requested();
        if (!conHolder.hasConnection()) {
            logger.debug("Fetching resumed JDBC Connection from DataSource");
            conHolder.setConnection(fetchConnection(dataSource));
        }
        return conHolder.getConnection();
    }
    // Else we either got no holder or an empty thread-bound holder here.

    logger.debug("Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource");
    Connection con = fetchConnection(dataSource);

    if (TransactionSynchronizationManager.isSynchronizationActive()) {
        try {
            // Use same Connection for further JDBC actions within the transaction.
            // Thread-bound object will get removed by synchronization at transaction completion.
            ConnectionHolder holderToUse = conHolder;
            if (holderToUse == null) {
                holderToUse = new ConnectionHolder(con);
            }
            else {
                holderToUse.setConnection(con);
            }
            holderToUse.requested();
            TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(
                    new ConnectionSynchronization(holderToUse, dataSource));
            holderToUse.setSynchronizedWithTransaction(true);
            if (holderToUse != conHolder) {
                TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(dataSource, holderToUse);
            }
        }
        catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            // Unexpected exception from external delegation call -> close Connection and rethrow.
            releaseConnection(con, dataSource);
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    return con;
}
```

and finally, we see:

```
if (conHolder != null && (conHolder.hasConnection() || conHolder.isSynchronizedWithTransaction())) {
    conHolder.requested();
    if (!conHolder.hasConnection()) {
        logger.debug("Fetching resumed JDBC Connection from DataSource");
        conHolder.setConnection(fetchConnection(dataSource));
    }
    return conHolder.getConnection();
}
```

and here we are. You can clearly see that **if** the connection exists, it's fetched and reused.

[See the full code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/74a014743ad5dccef92eddb5255c75b66c538279/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceUtils.java#L53) of how connection is created if it doesn't exist.

The [other methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) of JdbcTemplate API work in a similar manner.